# jQuery and Number Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

It seems that number formatting in javascript and jQuery is a bit of a quagmire.

I have a table which contains a bunch of numbers.  I want to change the numbers as the user interacts with jQuery elements on the page, but I also want the numbers to be formatted with commas and (+/-) signs as the user interacts with the table.  As far as I can tell, I can't perform any mathematical operations at all on the numbers in their formatted state.  Also, formatting the new numbers on the fly (without sending back to server) is possible with a regex, but inconvenient.

Is there a better way to format and work with this stuff on the fly?  I need to do math on the formatted numbers and generate new formatted numbers from the math.

Comment: If you are going to vote me down, at least say why.

Comment: If your numbers are floats, use `parseFloat`, if your numbers are integers, use `parseInt(...,10)`, no RegEx needed.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you need to show the code you have for people to give relevant suggestions, although this seems like it might fit [codereview.se] better. In any case you should separate data from presentation and *not* do math with formatted data. Keep a data structure with "pure" numbers and update the view based on them, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this, here a just a few:

1. Keep an array of objects in Javascript that will contain both the plain and formatted values. This can then easily be iterated over to both manipulate/calculate values and format & produce output.
2. Set a custom data element on each cell which will hold the plain value and then add the formatted value to the cell, something like `<td data-actual-val="3400">3,400</td>`
3. In each cell have a hidden input element which holds the plain value, and a span which holds the formatted value something along the lines of `<td><input type="hidden" class="actualVal" value="3400"><span class="formattedVal">3,400</span></td>`

We really can't do much more than that for you without you elaborating your question by adding the HTML and Javascript/jQuery you are currently using.

Comment: This was a good suggestion.  I just wound up sticking the non formatted numbers in window.variable when I initialize the table on the server, and manipulate them with javascript/jQuery once the user starts playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var profits=2489.8237
profits.toFixed(3) //returns 2489.824 (round up)
profits.toFixed(2) //returns 2489.82
profits.toFixed(7) //returns 2489.8237000 (padding)

var anumber=123.45
anumber.toPrecision(6) //returns 123.450 (padding)
anumber.toPrecision(4) //returns 123.5 (round up)
anumber.toPrecision(2) //returns 1.2e+2 (you figure it out!)


var profits=2489.8237
if (profits.toFixed) //if browser supports toFixed() method
profits.toFixed(2)
```

[credits](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/formatnumber.shtml)

also [this may help](http://numeraljs.com/)

Comment: The linked library is half of what I was looking for.  Thanks.